# Add parameter to URL when opening a Bootstrap Collapse item

Tags: jquery, html, parameters, bootstrap-4

I want to add an extra parameter to the URL when I'm opening a Bootstrap Collapse item.

At the moment, Bootstrap links to an anchor like `#collapseOne`. This anchor is hidden from the URL.

Is it possible to add an extra parameter and show it in the URL when I'm opening the Collapse item?

Here's the actual Bootstrap code:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
//var baseUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54400486/edit";
 var baseUrl = document.location;
$('#accordionExample').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    var collapseTarget = $(e.target).siblings('.card-header').find('button').attr('data-target');
    //url = document.location.href+"&myvar=" + collapseTarget;
     url = baseUrl +"?myvar=" + collapseTarget;
     alert(url);
    //document.location = url;
  })

})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
//var baseUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54400486/edit";
var baseUrl = document.location;
$('#accordionExample').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    var collapseTarget = $(e.target).siblings('.card-header').find('button').attr('data-target');
    //url = document.location.href+"&myvar=" + collapseTarget;
     url = baseUrl +"?myvar=" + collapseTarget;
    document.location = url;
  })

})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can find data target value when collapse item is clicked and put condition according that which or what value you want to pass in url.

Please try to use below code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 //var baseUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54400486/edit";
   var baseUrl = document.location;
 $('#accordionExample').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
   var collapseTarget = $(e.target).siblings('.card-header').find('button').attr('data-target');
  /*alert(collapseTarget);
  var value = '';
  if (collapseTarget == '#collapseOne') {
   value = 'one';
  } else if (collapseTarget == '#collapseTwo') {
    value = 'two';
  } else if (collapseTarget == '#collapseThree') {
    value = 'three';
  }*/

    url = baseUrl+"?myvar=" + collapseTarget;
    document.location = url;
 })
})
```

Comment: Do you want like this?

Comment: Yes, kind of. I need the `newvar` in the URL with a different parameter per collapse item

Comment: Just run above code snippet and check url i have added just one parameter.So you can put you condition according to that.Let me know if i have to add different parameters on different collapse click.First run the above snippet.

Comment: @Cray change snippet according to your requirement which will add different value on different click.Just check and run above snippet.Accept if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Is there any way to add the value without else/if? I don't know, how much collapse items there are. It's always different.

Comment: yes you can pull data-target value and assign it to url or you can add a custom attribute and pull tat attribut instead of data-target and pass that value.it will save if else code.

Comment: what value you want to add in url ?

Comment: I'm flexible with that. Let's say it is an ID

Comment: So i have added myvar value as collapse target value on click.

Comment: I had to define the `e.target` with `function(e)`. But there is no value in my url parameter. Also every link add another value in the URL.

Comment: I am not getting what exactly you want to do now..even i have edited code multiple time for you.I think above code should be fine for you to solve your problem by doing little bit changes according to your requirement.

Comment: I changed your code a bit. But for every click at a collapse element, the url gets a new parameter/value and gets longer and longer. In this case, I can't use the url parameter with PHP

Comment: Added baseUrl in code you can check last code snippet and let me know still you are facing this issue.So many times i have edited this just for you :-)

Comment: Thanks! But now there is no change to the URL at all